# Uploading .log file from local machine to FTP

Tags: c#

For a Cron service i am logging error in .log file on my local machine and then i am uploading that on ftp. So my problem is after uploading file on ftp I am getting incomplete and improper format of log file where as on local machine it is all right. can anybody help me out and let me know where i am missing.

**Example Log on local machine:**

Timestamp : 1/8/2014 5:50:14 PM

Candidate Email : aabc00@gmail.com

Status : Success :Created

**Same Log on ftp:**

te Email : aabc00@gmail.com

Status : Success :Created

**I am trying this code:**

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileInfo(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationLocation"]) + @"\" + fileName).Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                int bufferLength = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

                using (Stream uploadStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                    while (contentLength != 0)
                    {
                        uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                    uploadStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: are the file sizes different?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.  Your code is not considering size of the read information and looks like always saves the lest read.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileInfo(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationLocation"]) + @"\" + fileName).Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        int numBytesToRead = (int)fileStream.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;

        if (numBytesToRead > 0) 
        {       
            // get all file information in to the buffer
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int n = fileStream.Read(buffer, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                if (n == 0)
                    break;

                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }

            // now write that data to the file      
            using (Stream uploadStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```